# Error in read a .xlsx file using the pandas Library in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have problem in reading excel file from location.

**Error**

```
File "c:\users\dominic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1187
    print "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):"
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Syntax**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('DumpData 2.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

Kindly help to resolve the problem above

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: I am using Python 3

Comment: The print statement is replaced with the print function in Python3, this looks to be causing the issue.

Comment: @KeelanPool how do i go about it?

Comment: Show a minimal example of your code.

Comment: i'd suggest you open the file in excel and scroll to line 1187 (since that is what is being referenced in  the error message) and see if u can decipher why the error is so. alternatively, try reading the data directly via xlrd and see if it gives the same error. it is possible that one of the sheets (sheet_name=None implies u r reading in all the sheets) has an issue, or something is there that messes up the structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below syntax for python-3:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r'Path where the Excel file is stored\File name.xlsx', sheet_name='your Excel sheet name')
print (df)
```

Also, you can try to upgrade the `XLRD` for python-3

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade xlrd`

I have `Python 3` and `Pandas 0.23.4` and it's working fine.
Just check your pandas version using `print(pd.__version__)` and try to upgrade it.

If it doesn't work try to reinstall the `pandas & XLRD` module using `pip`

Comment: i have upgraded the ``` XLRD``` but  still not working

Comment: Could you tell me you pandas version:  you can get it using,  `print(pd.__version__)` - @dominictanui

Comment: the pandas version is 0.25.3

Comment: I have  reinstall all, but invain

Comment: Upgrading XLRD fixed the error, only for it to be replaced by another error : `XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported`…  Which can be fixed by [specifying another engine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65266497/812102).