# Pandas: how to make openpyxl the default engine for all read_excel operations?

Tags: excel, pandas

Since `read_excel`default engine [xlrd has been deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28547) in newer pandas releases, how do I make `openpyxl` the default engine of all my `pd.read_excel` calls?

Now, if I update pandas, I must put the parameter `engine="openpyxl"` in all my `pd.read_excel` calls. It looks unnecessary.

Comment: From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel): Otherwise if path_or_buffer is an xls format, xlrd will be used., **Otherwise if openpyxl is installed, then openpyxl will be used**.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy! You can do it by changing the default values of the method by going to the _base.py inside the environment's pandas folder. You can find it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__file__)
```

Once in the pandas folder, dive into the folder io > excel > _base.py

Open the file and find

```
def read_excel(...)
```

You will find the default value for engine. Change it to 'openpyxl'

If you're using vscode, simply right click on the instance of the method .read_excel and press F12, or go to the definition and change it right away.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pandas version 1.1.5 or other new version this might help:

Run `print(pd.__file__)` to see where your pandas library is stored. Usually, the file path would end in "Lib\site-packages\pandas". Then, open folder "io" and folder "excel" right after. You will find there the "_base.py" file.

Look for the `def __init__`. You will find there the default engine to read Excel files. It should be on line 849. I  should read:

```
if engine is None:
    engine = "openpyxl"
```