# Reading xlsx files on a mac in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl, xlrd

I am defining a pandas dataframe by reading an excel file saved locally:

```
 df_names = pd.read_excel(r'path/NAMES.xlsx', "Sheet1")
```

I am using pandas. However the above line leads to this error:

> raise ValueError("File is not a recognized excel file")

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I realise the fact it is a xlsx file complicates things but i don't really want to use xls files.

Comment: It looks that you are reading it with pandas not through openpyxl

Comment: @Jayvee Yeah you're correct, made the correction above

Comment: From the error message it's clear that there is a problem with the file: all XLSX files are zip files.

Comment: @CharlieClark I have now changed the file itself from scratch, pretty certain it is a valid xlsx file now. Changed the code to: df_names = xlrd.open_workbook(r'path/NAMES.xlsx') is this correct? It sill yield the same error: ValueError: File is not a recognized excel file

Answer (score 1):

If it is a valid xlsx file then then issue could be related to the pandas version; you can try by explicitly using openpyxl.
Assuming you have openpyxl installed then please try:

```
df_names = pd.read_excel(r'path/NAMES.xlsx',sheet_name= "Sheet1", engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: I made this edit the code but it leads to this error: zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file.

Comment: what pandas version would be ideal to solve this issue?

Comment: I believe the latest version should be fine but this error makes me think that it actually is something wrong with the file

Comment: there is a good discussion about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250207/pandas-cannot-open-an-excel-xlsx-file

Comment: I have now changed the file itself from scratch, pretty certain it is a valid xlsx file now. Changed the code to: df_names = xlrd.open_workbook(r'path/NAMES.xlsx') is this correct? It sill yield the same error: ValueError: File is not a recognized excel file

Comment: Please try opening it with ooenpyxl