# Error: File is not a recognized excel file when I try to read an excel file - pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've been trying to read an excel file with read_excel pandas method `df_archivo = pd.read_excel(relative_file_path)` but it throws me an error.

> ValueError: File is not a recognized excel file

```
def procesar_archivos_bitacora(directorio):
   # Obtener la lista de archivos en el directorio
   lista_archivos = get_files_in_path(directorio)
   folder='input/'
   download_all_files(lista_archivos,folder)
   for archivo in lista_archivos:
      local_path = join(folder,archivo)
      print('joined path: ',local_path)
      formatear_bitacora(local_path)
```

As you can see, I have my reading method inside a loop. 'joined path' is like I was expecting. And inside input folder there are only excel files.

The steps I'm following are:

1. I download the file from a sharepoint directory
2. I join the download folder directory with every downloaded file name
3. Then I try to read each file using a loop

Comment: Do these files have the .xls or .xlsx extension or both?

Comment: @aozk all those files have. xlsx extension.

Comment: Can you try pd.read_excel with parameter engine='openpyxl' ?

Comment: @aozk When I tried it, it showed me this error: Bad Zip FIle.

Comment: There must be a problem with files, can you open them in excel without any errors  / warnings?

Comment: @aozk I followed your suggestion:
1) If I download directly the file, it works when opening
2) If I follow the same steps described above on my jupyter notebook, it works too
3) But if I run my .py file with those steps from my vscode editor, it fails. The file got corrupted.

Comment: I ran into this issued when opening an *old* XLS file (Excel 2), and pandas could not read it. Ended up using `xlrd` to read the file manually into a `StringIO`, then feeding that into pandas as a CSV.  (Perhaps the extension should be `.xls` and has been mislabeled and became misleading as to the true issue?)

Answer (score 0):

[xlrd](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is supporting only .xls files. There are two workarounds:

**First** (recommended by me) is to install [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Then put ***openpyxl*** into engine parameter of [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

```
pd.read_excel(local_path, engine='openpyxl')
```

**Second** is to downgrade ***xlrd*** version

```
pip install xlrd==1.2.0
```

Comment: OP's error message suggests that xlrd is not the issue... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250207/pandas-cannot-open-an-excel-xlsx-file