# Is there a different way to read .xls and .xlsx file in Python using Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Is there a different way to read .xls and .xlsx file? I am currently using read_excel method but it doesn't work with .xlsx file.

df = pd.read_excel(r'path/sample.xlsx',skiprows=2)

It doesn't work with .xlsx file and it gives the below error.

Error:
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas cannot open an Excel (.xlsx) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250207/pandas-cannot-open-an-excel-xlsx-file)

Comment: I appreciate that link just for the extra saucy first answer. :D

Comment: the link helped. Thanks.